# TYPO3, Extbase: mysqli error message, commands out of sync

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I try to update a really old extbase extension which is from another programmer. TYPO3-Version is 8.7.13

The following function in my Repository throws the error:

"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException thrown in file
/Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.13/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php in line 249."

And this ist the function:

```
Public Function delete($standort, $month) 
{
    $m = date('m',$month);
    $y = date('Y',$month);

    $sql = "
    DELETE FROM mytable
    WHERE standort = ".$standort." AND FROM_UNIXTIME( monat,  '%m' ) = $m AND FROM_UNIXTIME( monat,  '%Y' ) = $y ";
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->statement($sql);
    $query->execute(TRUE);
 }
```

with $query->execute(FALSE); no error is thrown but the sql is not executed. With $query->execute(TRUE); the error appears but the sql will be executed.

Can anybody help? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing this statement to Doctrine? You can find the documentation here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Database/BasicCrud/Index.html#delete-a-row

Comment: It works - but: functions like FROM_UNIXTIME seems not possible with doctrine so i had to work around in php ... Thanks!